# Can we use JAR file into JRuby?

Tags: jar, jruby, jrubyonrails

By adding Jar file into the Jruby project.Can We use a java classes of the that Jar file into the Jruby?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I have a project with the GUI build on java (using NetBeans) and I do the rest in ruby, controllers, etc. I only needed to declare the variables (methods) public to access them (I am not 100% shure if you can avoid this). You can make a section with aliases in Ruby to make them look like ruby syntax. Note, that you also have to require the jar in your Ruby code.